# Firestore rest api to make authenticated requests in arduino ide

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, arduino, firebase-authentication, esp32

i'm making an IOT project with an esp32

the webApi key is hardcoded in a `#define`.
i have this code working for the auth part

```
String url = "https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signInWithPassword?key=" + String(apiKey);
http.setTimeout(2000);
http.begin(url);
http.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
String dataSent = "{\"email\":\"" + String(email) + "\",\"password\":\"" + String(pswd) + "\",\"returSecureToken\":\"true\"}";
// Issue the HTTP POST request.
int status = http.POST(dataSent);
Serial.println(status);
```

it returns 200 and the response is parsed, and the `idToken` is stored in my `String token`

when i try to make a patch to firestore it returns 401

```
 String url = "https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1/projects/timer-test-soulx/databases/(default)/documents/devices/" + uniqueID + "?key=[" + apiKey + "]"; //working ok
http.setTimeout(1000);
http.begin(url);
http.addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + String(token)); //needs fixing
http.addHeader("Accept", "application/json");
http.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
// Issue the HTTP POST request.
int status = http.PATCH(dataSent);
```

my rules are `allow read, write: if request.auth != null;`

already tried changing the rules to allow read and write, then commenting out the authorization header and it works perfectly. so i think its clear the problem is the authorization header. am i using a wrong token?

Comment: This is exactly how the authentication with the API should be done, so this should be working, do you have some other account to test? Maybe this is a problem with the specific account you are using.

Comment: i do have another one, imma try using that one. also i tried with this change ' http.addHeader("Bearer", token);' and now it returns 403 wich i understand is a problem with permissions. what is weird is that i keep geting 403 even when modifying the rules to allow all reads and writes

Comment: hmm, maybe there is something misconfigured in the firebase rules if you get a 403, could you share the whole fragment of the relevant firebase rule? that means with the `match` part and everything.

Comment: @RafaelLemos i think the problem is with the authentication, i made another question about it here:  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67276572/firebase-auth-rest-api-not-returning-the-full-body-response-in-arduino-ide) _italic_ **bold** 
 . to be short, the response im geting is not the full response of the same request made with postman (idToken is not full lenght, and is missing expiration and refreshToken), and when i parse the idToken that problem is carried to the firestore request