# firebase auth rest api not returning the full body response in arduino ide

Tags: c, firebase, rest, arduino, firebase-authentication

i've been stuck in a problem with firebase auth rest api in arduino ide, the following code returns code 200

```
String url = "https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signInWithPassword?key=" + String(apiKey);
http.setTimeout(5000);
http.begin(url);
http.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
String dataSent = "{\"email\":\"" + String(email) + "\",\"password\":\"" + String(pswd) + "\",\"returSecureToken\":\"true\"}";
int status = http.POST(dataSent);
Serial.println(status);
if (status <= 0)
{
    Serial.printf("HTTP error: %s\n",
                  http.errorToString(status).c_str());
    return false;
}
// Read the response.
String payload = http.getString();
Serial.println(payload);
```

but when i look in my serial monitor the response looks like this:

```
   {
     kind: "the kind of response",
     localId: "someId",
     email: "myEmail",
     displayName: "myDisplayName",
     idToken: "someIdToken",
     registered: "someBoolean",
   }
```

witch aparently is ok but when i try the same http request in postman the response includes also `refreshToken` and `expiresIn`

with even more investigation i found that `localId` from postman is about 980 characters while the `localId` from my arduino code is only about 680

im trying (and failing) to use the localId to authenticate a request with the firestore api and i think this difference in lenght is what's been buggingme.
could that really be the problem ?

Comment: I wonder if this has to do with the parser not being able to interpret the tokens, you can measure the bit size of the response and compare it.

Comment: The response doesn't match any documented rest API response payloads. https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/use-rest-api#section-create-email-password so I suspect it maybe related to the library or the device

Comment: @DIGIByte i tried changing to anonymus authentication `
  String url = "https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signUp?key=" + String(apiKey);
  http.setTimeout(5000);
  http.begin(url);
  http.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
  String dataSent = "{\"returSecureToken\":\"true\"}";
  int status = http.POST(dataSent);` and the response is perfectly fine including the `refreshToken`and `expiresIn`

Comment: the idToken i get now is 850 characters, not the 980 from postman using the signupWithPassword but if i try to request from firestore api with this token it works

Comment: just tried anonymus authentication in postman and it does return a tokenId of 850 characters... my guess is that http.getString() is not large enough to hold the response of signInWithPassword. Does that make any sense?

Comment: makes sense, I suspect its due to the library itself, you will need to do more investigation into finding a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
      method: "POST",
      body: JSON.stringify({
        email: enteredEmail,
        password: enteredPassword,
        returnSecureToken: true,
      }),
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
    })
```

**NB:** Make sure {returnSecureToken: true} is part of your request body

Comment: "Make sure {returnSecureToken: true} is part of your request body" this was my problem but it was a dumb thing.
i had written "returSecureToken" instead of "returnSecureToken". my whole problem was a typo. felt pretty dumb when i found out

Comment: by the way, JSON.stringify looks way cleaner than having many " " and /. thank you